# Is it possible under iOS to proxy requests from one app to an external resource?

Tags: ios

Is it possible under iOS to proxy requests from one app to an external resource?

**Actors in this scenario**:

1. An external resource (Resource-1)
2. A Proxy-app (runs in the background most of the time but has a GUI for some interaction)
3. A Client-app

**Pre-conditions**:

- Client-app-1 and Proxy-app is installed on the same mobile device.
- The mobile device and the external resource "Resource-1" are both
  connected to the same local WLAN.

Now, Client-app-1 wants to call Proxy-app (somehow) to perform an action or fetch information. Proxy-app receives the request and, if intelligle, calls Resource-1 to satisfy the request.

Is this even possible under iOS? Can it be done without Proxy-app being moved to the foreground? And what primary mechanisms would be used to accomplish this inter-app communication?

I'm sorry for the abstract nature of the question.

Comment: I am curious why you would not just do this in one app. What is there to gain by taking this approach?

Comment: @ryantxr Forgot to mention that there may be more than client-app. Each client-app may be developed and sold separately and would utilize different parts of the external resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it's not simple. The tool you want is a [NetworkExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension). In particular you want a [Network Tunneling Protocol Client](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovider). This can be tied to a specific application (see `appRules`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm unsure of how to apply these tools to the problem. Would you exand a little, please? Do you mean the Proxy-app would implement the NetworkExtension? And Client-app-1 to Proxy-app communication occur via the extension? Is a VPN required to use Network Tunneling Protocol Client? Sorry if I'm completely off.

Comment: It's a very large topic, and too big to cover in a SO answer IMO. But yes, the proxy-app would implement a network extension (as an app extension; the proxy-app itself would be the UI you're describing. What you're building is the equivalent of a VPN (whether you mean it to be a VPN or not, that's how to think about it). Start here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/707/  and while older, this one may also provide some insight: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/717/.  It's not really well documented; you'll have to explore somewhat.